# usage of double is

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The common theme --what makes it origami-- **is folding is** how we create the form.
*A ted talk from Robert Lang about magic of origami*

I thing it is a kind of emphasize in spoken language.

It mixes two sentences.
The common theme is folding.
The common theme is how we create the form.

But I'm not sure

Comment: That is not a good sentence and should not be emulated.  It is the kind of error speakers make when they lose track of what they're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in thinking the two sentences have been combined into

> **folding** is how we create the form.

**folding** is a gerund used as a noun. I could have easily have been

> **paper and folding** is how we create the form.